# Equivalent of "Styles" pane in Word for Mac

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, office365

It is surprisingly difficult to find a definitive and up-to-date answer to my question: Is there an equivalent of the MS Word for Windows 365 "Styles" pane for MS Word for Mac 365? This is the pane I'm talking about:

[image: Styles pane under Word 365 for Windows]

There are also symbols behind each style for paragraph (the "No Spacing" style in the image) and character ("Highlighted") styles. I cannot find any such similar distinction for Word on Mac. So, my questions are:

- Is there an equivalent of the Styles pane in Word for Mac?
- Is there a distinction between character and paragraph styles in Word for Mac?

Thank you!

I am using Word for Mac Version 16.81 (24011420).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to find something in an app on Mac.

- Click the Help menu.
- Type part of the word you're looking for.
- Follow the floating arrow.

[image]

Note that Office for Windows & Office for Mac are designed & built by two completely different teams, so there's not always an exact match for each & every function/pref.

Comment: I see! Thank you ... so there is, indeed, a distinction between different types of styles and there is something similar to the Styles pane! It's a pity though that the Mac version blocks access to the document itself as long as it's open.

Answer (score 1):

@Swolf and @Tetsujin -- There is a Styles Pane option in Word for Mac 365 in the Home Ribbon.
*I am using Microsoft(R) Word for Mac Version 16.81 (24011420) with a Microsoft 365 Subscription*
[image: Word Mac 365 Styles Pane Ribbon & Side bar]

If you have the window narrow, its in the the Styles section
[image: If you have the window narrow]
[image]

Comment: Hmm… yes - that does lead to a 'different thing by a different path'. Remarkably inconsistent [& I hate those ribbons on apps anyway, they kill key-commandability for the power-user:\

Comment: Yes, I know that one – thanks! In this Styles pane, there are no indicators of what type of style it is, though. It's weird as @Tetsujin said...